# Cannot save image filtered in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, python

I am trying to save image after applying filter, but after saving operation on my disk I have not `dst_1`, but `img`.

```
img = cv2.imread(images[14], 1)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.float32)/25
dst_1 = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("path/f.jpg", dst_1)
```

When I am using `imshow` after applying filter, I see what I expected to see - filtered image.
Does anybody know, what is the reason of this `imwrite` behavior or where is my mistake?

Comment: Change the path to some other folder, just for testing.

Comment: Try using absolute path where you want to save the image. If it is in linux make sure you have permissions to write in the folder (or the user that executes the script)

Comment: I'am om macOS. I've changed path to absolute, but the situation is the same.
I may write image, but I have wrong image written. Here is the problem.

Comment: On my system it works. Is path really the name of the folder or a variable which you have made part of a string by mistake ?

Comment: When I am replacing applying filter with grayscaling, everything is ok! It is very strange!

Comment: can you edit a post and show an example image and what it is being saved? or at least can you say what is different?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/qIqtI) is default image. [This](https://imgur.com/a/KfLWr) is an image after applying filter. But after saving filtered image using `imwrite`, I am having the first variant on my disk :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not with the way you are saving the file, but rather your filter is not doing what you think it is doing, thus it looks no different to the image you are saving.

OpenCV opens the image in BGR format, and the second image you showed in your comment is the same image, but in RGB format, OpenCV has a function that can do this for you, so please try the below code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread(images[14], 1)
dst_1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite("path/f.jpg", dst_1)
```

This should achieve the output you are looking for, hope it helps!

Comment: Filter is okay, because I can see its results using `imshow` function. But when I am saving image - there is no results

Comment: I tested the code you have in your question on my ubuntu machine, and when I used imshow it looked exactly the same

Comment: Please edit your code so it is exactly the same as what you have on your machine, including the imshow